# Database Trigger that finds nearest record from another table after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query

I have two tables(a,b), both with a shape or geometry field. I want a trigger to run after an insert on table a to find the (single) nearest spatial record from table b. I have looked into the STDistance function with little luck. Table a is unique.

**AFTER INSERT**

Table a

```
OBJECTID,RoadID

12345,NULL
```

Table b

```
AssetID

RD12345

RD12233

RD12333

RD12222
```

STDistnace would say Table a.OBJECTID 12345 nearest Table b.AssetID = RD12222

**Result**

Table a

```
OBJECTID,RoadID

12345,RD12222
```

I have completed some preliminary testing which returns all matching records (from both tables) but I am trying to condense it down to only the matching record with the lowest distance, hence the aggregate function(MIN) on STDistance.

```
SELECT TableA.AssetID,MIN(TableA.Shape.STDistance(TableB.Shape)) AS DIST, TableB.AssetID AS RoadID 
FROM TableA, TableB
GROUP BY TableA.AssetID, TableB.AssetID
HAVING MIN(TableA.Shape.STDistance(TableB.Shape)) < 250
ORDER BY AssetID
```

The result I get is a many to many relationship by distance for all records. If I apply the aggregate function(MIN) I can reduce it significantly however the Table a unique id's still duplicate. The plan is once the select statement worked I would translate it into my trigger - I would prefer the answer to be based on how it would be implemented in a trigger.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks marc_s. 
SELECT a.assetid,b.Assetid AS ROAD, b.shape.STDistance(a.shape) AS DIST
FROM sde.TableA a
join sde.TableB b
on b.shape.STDistance(a.shape) <250

Comment: How 12345 is nearest to Table b.AssetID = RD12222?

Comment: By leveraging the STDistance function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) Both tables have a geometry field.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `CROSS APPLY ... SELECT TOP 1.... ORDER BY distance` to cross join two tables and select the nearest record:

```
SELECT A.OBJECTID, NearestB.B_ID, NearestB.Distance
FROM TableA A
    CROSS APPLY(
        select TOP 1 
            A.Shape.STDistance(B.Shape) AS distance,
            B.AssetID as B_ID
        from TableB B
        order by 1
    ) NearestB
```

And the trigger might be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TableA_Insertion_SetNearestB ON TableA
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA (
        OBJECTID,
        Shape,
        RoadID
    ) SELECT
        INSERTED.OBJECTID,
        INSERTED.Shape,
        NearestB.B_ID
    ) FROM
        INSERTED
        CROSS APPLY(
            select TOP 1 
                INSERTED.Shape.STDistance(B.Shape) AS distance,
                B.AssetID as B_ID
            from TableB B
            order by 1
        ) NearestB
END
GO
```